# Error in Postgresql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "TheGecko"

Tags: django, postgresql

Im trying to use PostgreSQL with django and I get that error when running `python3 manage.py migrate`:
`connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "TheGecko"`

I was following this guide:https://djangocentral.com/using-postgresql-with-django/

Here is my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'websitedb',
    'USER':'TheGecko',
    'PASSWORD':'xx',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':5432,
  }
}
```

Also, even though I entered that line: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE websitedb TO TheGecko;`, when I do \l, I get this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaJQT.png). Shouldn't the owner be TheGecko?

I've looked over the web and nothing I could read worked for me.
Please help.

Comment: No, as: `...TO TheGecko` would fold to lower case `thegecko` per [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). From the looks of it you did the same thing when you created the role. Do `\du` to verify.  If you want to preserve case you need to double quote the identifier: `"TheGecko"`.

Comment: Yes that was the error, it's working now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I also revieved same error and resolved by doing below changes:

```
DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE':
    'django.db.backends.postgresql', 'NAME': 'websitedb',
    'USER':'postgres', 'PASSWORD':'xx', 'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':'5432', } }
```

---